# Adding Element to Middle of an Array (Data Structures)

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, generics

I'm having trouble implementing an add method to an array structure for my data structures class and am not able to find a way to wrap my head around how to do this correctly. I am aware this is an impractical way handling data, but hey data structures.

Instructions:

> The add method ensures that this set contains the specified element.
>   Neither duplicates nor null values are allowed. The method returns
>   true if this set was modified (i.e., the element was added) and false
>   otherwise. If the array is full, you must “resize” to an array twice
>   as large. Note that the constraint on the generic type parameter T of
>   the ArraySet class ensures that there is a natural order on the values
>   stored in an ArraySet. You must maintain the internal array in
>   ascending natural order at all times. The time complexity of the add
>   method must be O ( N ), where N is the number of elements in the set.

**We are able to use the Array and Iterator classes only! Please do not give an answer using arraylists.**

My Psudocode is:

> Check element exists, check if array is full, if full double size,
>   compare elements to find an index where we can maintain natural order
>   and insert element or find the duplicate and exit, *copy array from
>   top down and combine with inserted element and bottom part.*

Actual Code:

```
//Given Fields
T[] elements;
int size;

//Add Method
public boolean add(T element) {
        if (element != null) {
            int index = -1;
            int last_compare = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                int compare = elements[i].compareTo(element);
                if (compare > 0 && last_compare < 0) { //larger element, last element was smaller. 
                    if (isFull()) {
                        resize(elements.length * 2);
                    }
                    index = i;
                    break;
                } else if (compare == 0) {
                    return false;
                }
                last_compare = compare;
            }

            T[] temp = null;
            //Need to copy the array here

        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I don't know how to insert this correctly while maintaining O(N) time complexity.

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't double the size before you know that you need to add another element.

Comment: Have you thought about using an ArraySet and sorting it? Wouldn't this fullfil the requirements? Sorting of course means that <T> is Comparable ;)

Comment: Well that's what we're supposed to be doing is creating an ArraySet class that implements a given set class.

Comment: The condition `compare > 0 && last_compare < 0` implies that another element is always added *between* two existing elements - something that can't be true all the time.

Comment: Check java.lang.System.arraycopy  for copying the full array to the one twice its size.

Comment: Why not use Arrays.sort()?

Comment: Ah I see what you mean Alexander.. haha that would be much easier. But still begs the questions of how to add to the array. I looked at System.arraycopy, and it seems like I'd have to copy the array up from the index I need to add to and merge, is there a better way to do that?